# html5 + jquery - How to create buttons dynamically

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I make:

By clicking a button should create a new button inside a `<div>`

PS: Each new button will access data from a position of a list

Anyone know where the logic error?

Comment: What is the question? can you make it a jsfiddle so you can tell us what's wrong?

Comment: this question baffles me... OP please clarify the desired result as your code doesn't give any real clues. from the looks of your code, it seems to me that instead of looking for an answer to this question, your immediate goal should be to learn javascript. http://www.w3schools.com/  http://www.codecademy.com/#!/exercises/0

Comment: Just want to dynamically create butões where each button will access a position in a list

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you may encounter is to bind events clicks for created buttons

You should use the `on()` method
There are 2 implementations of `on()`. One allows binding directly to elements but those elements must exist, and does not account for futures.

The other method is a delegation method. You delegate the handler to a higher level elementt or the document. This method catches the event as it bubbles

http://api.jquery.com/on/

you must also increment "i" value => `i++` when each buttons were created

Comment: My problem is that:
Every time I create a new button and put it to an event, the old buttons take this same event

Comment: Is that the values ​​of the variable "i" change?

Comment: Could you edit your question by providing a more complete code, after that All SO users can help you